# Why is this CUDA kernel slow?

Tags: c++, cuda, bit-shift, texture2d

I need help getting my cuda program run faster. NVIDIA visual profiler shows poor performance saying "Low Compute Utilization 1.4%":

[image]

The code is below. First kernel preparations:

```
void laskeSyvyydet(int& tiilet0, int& tiilet1, int& tiilet2, int& tiilet3) {

cudaArray *tekstuuriSisaan, *tekstuuriUlos;

//take care of synchronazion
cudaEvent_t cEvent;
cudaEventCreate(&cEvent);

//let's take control of OpenGL textures
cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, &cuda.cMaxSyvyys);
cudaEventRecord(cEvent, 0);
cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, &cuda.cDepthTex);
cudaEventRecord(cEvent, 0);

//need to create CUDA pointers
cudaGraphicsSubResourceGetMappedArray(&tekstuuriSisaan, cuda.cDepthTex, 0, 0);
cudaGraphicsSubResourceGetMappedArray(&tekstuuriUlos, cuda.cMaxSyvyys, 0, 0);

cudaProfilerStart();

//launch kernel
cLaskeSyvyydet(tiilet0, tiilet1, tiilet2, tiilet3, tekstuuriSisaan, tekstuuriUlos);
cudaEventRecord(cEvent, 0);

cudaProfilerStop();

//release textures back to OpenGL
cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(1, &cuda.cMaxSyvyys, 0);
cudaEventRecord(cEvent, 0);
cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(1, &cuda.cDepthTex, 0);
cudaEventRecord(cEvent, 0);

//final synchronazion
cudaEventSynchronize(cEvent);
cudaEventDestroy(cEvent);
}
```

Kernel launch:

```
void cLaskeSyvyydet(int& tiilet0, int& tiilet1, int& tiilet2, int& tiilet3, cudaArray* tekstuuriSisaan, cudaArray* tekstuuriUlos) {

cudaBindTextureToArray(surfRefSisaan, tekstuuriSisaan);
cudaBindSurfaceToArray(surfRefUlos, tekstuuriUlos);

    int blocksW = (int)ceilf( tiilet0 / 32.0f );
    int blocksH = (int)ceilf( tiilet1 / 32.0f );
    dim3 gridDim( blocksW, blocksH, 1 );
    dim3 blockDim(32, 32, 1 );

kLaskeSyvyydet<<<gridDim, blockDim>>>(tiilet0, tiilet1, tiilet2, tiilet3);

}
```

And the kernel:

```
__global__ void kLaskeSyvyydet(const int tiilet0, const int tiilet1, const int tiilet2, const int tiilet3) {

//first define indexes
    unsigned int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int j = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    if (i >= tiilet0 || j >= tiilet1) return;

//if we are inside boundaries, let's find the greatest depth value
    unsigned int takana=0;
    unsigned int ddd;
    uchar4 syvyys;
    uchar4 dd;

//there's possibly four different tile sizes to choose between
    if (j!=tiilet1-1 && i!=tiilet0-1) {

    for (int y=j*BLOCK_SIZE; y<(j+1)*BLOCK_SIZE; y++) {
        for (int x=i*BLOCK_SIZE; x<(i+1)*BLOCK_SIZE; x++) {
            dd=tex2D(surfRefSisaan, x, y);
            ddd=(dd.x << 24) | (dd.y << 16) | (dd.z << 8) | (dd.w);
            takana=max(takana, ddd);
        }
    }

    } else if (j==tiilet1-1 && i!=tiilet0-1) {

    for (int y=j*BLOCK_SIZE; y<j*BLOCK_SIZE+tiilet3; y++) {
        for (int x=i*BLOCK_SIZE; x<(i+1)*BLOCK_SIZE; x++) {
            dd=tex2D(surfRefSisaan, x, y);
            ddd=(dd.x << 24) | (dd.y << 16) | (dd.z << 8) | (dd.w);
            takana=max(takana, ddd);
            }
        }

    } else if (j!=tiilet1-1 && i==tiilet0-1) {

    for (int y=j*BLOCK_SIZE; y<(j+1)*BLOCK_SIZE; y++) {
        for (int x=i*BLOCK_SIZE; x<i*BLOCK_SIZE+tiilet2; x++) {
            dd=tex2D(surfRefSisaan, x, y);
            ddd=(dd.x << 24) | (dd.y << 16) | (dd.z << 8) | (dd.w);
            takana=max(takana, ddd);
        }
    }

    } else if (j==tiilet1-1 && i==tiilet0-1) {

    for (int y=j*BLOCK_SIZE; y<j*BLOCK_SIZE+tiilet3; y++) {
        for (int x=i*BLOCK_SIZE; x<i*BLOCK_SIZE+tiilet2; x++) {
            dd=tex2D(surfRefSisaan, x, y);
            ddd=(dd.x << 24) | (dd.y << 16) | (dd.z << 8) | (dd.w);
            takana=max(takana, ddd);
        }
    }
    }

//if there's empty texture, then we choose the maximum possible value
    if (takana==0) {
    takana=1000000000;
    }

//after slicing the greatest 32bit depth value into four 8bit pieces we write the value into another texture
    syvyys.x=(takana & 0xFF000000) >> 24;
    syvyys.y=(takana & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
    syvyys.z=(takana & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
    syvyys.w=(takana & 0x000000FF) >> 0;

    surf2Dwrite(syvyys, surfRefUlos, i*sizeof(syvyys), j, cudaBoundaryModeZero);

}
```

Please help me get this working faster, I have no ideas...

Comment: provide a complete program that someone else could compile and run (a [mcve]).  Also include your timing or performance measurement, as well as your platform (GPU, OS, CUDA version).

Comment: What's the purpose of your program?

Comment: Robert Crovella: I'll try to give complete one, but its difficult to separate from unnecessary codes. This consists a separate dll, I try to get rid of it. Eric: It simplifies depth buffer of Tiled Forward Engine. talonmies: Please, tell more...

Comment: @mamannon: There is nothing to tell here - you google for "cuda reduction" and you get 390,000 hits. The first ten of which are all excellent references. But looking at your profiler output, your kernel is taking 5ms to run. Is that *really* slow?

Comment: Making your kernel run faster won't improve the "low compute utilization" result.  It will only make it worse.  You don't seem to understand what the profiler is telling you.  Your program is being profiled for 0.3 sec, and of that time, only 5ms is being spent in the kernel.  What makes you think that making this kernel run faster will improve that measurement?  It will only make it "worse".

Comment: Good points, talonmies and Robert. If you look at screenshot above, you note that most of time is spent with two cudaFree calls and one cudaGraphisGLRegisterBuffer, right? Well, the graph is lying, because if remove those calls from code, another remaining calls will take their place and compute utilization is about the same. Anyway, you're still right, the WHOLE program seems to be profiled despite cudaProfilerStart() and cudaProfilerStop() calls you can see in my code. But the reality is, that the above code, if I debug it over by one step, takes a while, it doesn't happen immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a 2D `int` input array of the size

```
((tiilet0-1)*BLOCK_SIZE+tiilet2, ((tiilet1-1)*BLOCK_SIZE)+tiilet3)
```

Each of your thread will sequentially read all elements in an input block of the size

```
(BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE)
```

and write the the maximum of the each input block to an 2D result array of the size

```
(tiilet0, tiilet1)
```

Compared to the coalesced memory access, this may be the worst possible way to access the global memory, even with 2D texture. You many want to read about coalesced memory access.

https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/how-access-global-memory-efficiently-cuda-c-kernels/

Generally you put too much work into one thread. Given the way you map the CUDA thread blocks to your input array, I guess unless you have a VERY large input, your `gridDim` will be too small to fully utilize the GPU.

For better performance you may want to change from one CUDA thread per input block to one CUDA thread block per input block (`int[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE]`), and use [parallel reduction](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/samples/6_Advanced/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf) to find the block-wise maximum.